# Upgrade to MVC4 Targeting 4.0 and VS2010, but MS Build still looking for v11.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

We have upgraded our MVC3 project to MVC4 running in VS2010, still targeting the 4.0 framework (not quite ready for 4.5).  This all works fine in development, but the build is failing on the build server (using Jenkins/Hudson, sadly), with the following message:

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I looked for an  statement in the project file to match this, but there is none.  The second line (below) in the csproj is explicitly targeting v10.0:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

I suppose the first one could somehow be resolving to v11.0, but I'm not sure where that would be coming from.  The solution has been opened in VS 2012 at least once, so I'm assuming it inserted something somewhere, but not sure what.

In my dev environment, I've renamed the VS 2012 path and can still load and build my project in VS 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it - the answer is more or less here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx

Basically, if you ever open an MVC4 project in VS2012, it changes the project file to dynamically detect the VS version and default to v10.0 if that value isn't found.

I'm not 100% sure where the v11.0 was coming from on the build server.  Reverting the .sln file did not seem to make a difference.  However, after reverting that particular change to the .csproj file, it builds successfully.

Specifically, I commented the added lines like so:

```
<!--
      <PropertyGroup>
        <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
        <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
-->
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<!--
      <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
-->
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Comment: Commenting these out seems to break the Publishing though. Any ideas about that? "The target GatherAllFilesToPublish does not exist in the project" error starts to occur without them there.